# BIRT Build standalone report generator in a JAR

Tags: java, maven, birt

I have built a Java 1.8 application under Maven in Eclipse that allows me to generate BIRT reports in a programmatic way without the need for the UI. Within Eclipse everything works fine. If I compile the code into a JAR file and try to run it however I run into problems with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`s. Clearly I have a missing dependancy but I don't know how to resolve the problem.

The error is

```
java -cp target/* com.resonancex.scheduler.Scheduler

Establishing conection...
    Connected
    Got products to report
    ProductId=1 ProductType=BREN Isin=XS1939207996 Template=BREN_MU
    * birtEngine EngineConfig: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineConfig.emitterConfigs={html=org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.HTMLEmitterConfig@71bbf57e};
    * Birt Engine Startring ....
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/CoreException
            at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform.createPlatformLauncher(Platform.java:115)
            at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform.startup(Platform.java:74)
            at com.resonancex.scheduler.BirtEngine.start(BirtEngine.java:33)
            at com.resonancex.scheduler.BirtEngine.getBirtEngine(BirtEngine.java:47)
            at com.resonancex.scheduler.BIRTReportGenerator.setReportCustom(BIRTReportGenerator.java:67)
            at com.resonancex.scheduler.Scheduler.generateAllReports(Scheduler.java:68)
            at com.resonancex.scheduler.Scheduler.main(Scheduler.java:79)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I added the library `org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.8.0-20180626-4.8.0` which appears to be the required BIRT runtime. Can anyone give me a few pointers as to what else I may need?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else tries to do this I thought I would list the libraries I needed to install to get standalone BIRT report generation running running. The list is as follows. Obviously this list may change over time so keep that in mind:

```
axis-1.4.jar
batik-anim-1.7.jar
batik-awt-util-1.7.jar
batik-bridge-1.7.jar
batik-css-1.7.jar
batik-dom-1.7.jar
batik-gvt-1.7.jar
batik-i18n-1.9.jar
batik-parser-1.7.jar
batik-script-1.7.jar
batik-svg-dom-1.7.jar
batik-transcoder-1.7.jar
batik-util-1.8.jar
batik-xml-1.7.jar
hibernate-agroal-5.4.9.Final.jar
icu4j-4.8.jar
itext-2.1.7.jar
mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar
org.apache.batik.css-1.6.0.jar
org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.8.0-20180626-4.8.0.jar
org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.14.0.v20180417-0825-4.8.0.jar
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda-3.5.0.201603142002.jar
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer-3.3.0.201603142002.jar
org.eclipse.emf.common-2.16.0.jar
org.eclipse.emf.ecore-2.11.1.jar
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi-2.11.1.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.10.0.v20180412-1130-4.8.0.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.8.0.v20180426-1327-4.8.0.jar
org.eclipse.osgi_3.13.0.v20180409-1500-4.8.0.jar
org.mozilla.javascript-1.7.5.v201504281450.jar
org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.1.v200903091627-4.8.0.jar
org.w3c.dom.svg-1.1.0.jar
sac-1.3.jar
xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
```